# String manipulation in Lua: Swap characters in a string

Tags: string, lua, swap

I'm trying to do a function in Lua that swaps the characters in a string.
Can somebody help me ?

Here is an example:

```
Input =  "This LIBRARY should work with any string!"  
Result = "htsil biaryrs ohlu dowkrw ti hna ytsirgn!"
```

Note: The space is also swapped

Thank You Very Much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest and clearest solution is this:

```
Result = Input:gsub("(.)(.)","%2%1")
```

Comment: +1, but to fully conform, it would have to be `Input:lower():gsub("(.)(.)","%2%1")`

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
input =  "This LIBRARY should work with any string!"

function swapAlternateChars(str)
   local t={}

   -- Iterate through the string two at a time 
   for i=1,#str,2 do
     first = str:sub(i,i)
     second = str:sub(i+1,i+1)
     t[i] = second
     t[i+1] = first
   end
   return table.concat(t)
end

print(input)
print(swapAlternateChars(input))
```

Prints:

```
This LIBRARY should work with any string!
hTsiL BIARYRs ohlu dowkrw ti hna ytsirgn!
```

If you need the output as lower case you could always end it with:

```
output = swapAlternateChars(input)
print(string.lower(output))
```

Note, in this example, I'm not actually editing the string itself, since strings in Lua are immutable. Here's a read: [Modifying a character in a string in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249629/modifying-a-character-in-a-string-in-lua)

I've used a table to avoid overhead from concatenating to a string because each concatenation may allocate a new string in memory.