# Lua replacing the first numeric character of dynamic random string with _a-zA-Z

Tags: string, lua

So I have a very dynamic string that will consist of letters and numbers and underscores [A-Za-z0-9_]

If the first character of the string is numeric I am trying to remove and / or replace that first numeric character only with a non numeric character [a-zA-Z_]

Example :

```
local string = "5fLkQZ73ziBzHMTgaoSBfDb9qa1q3qdqBGwJ4Mw1gkY782VhVr8Itmheq03mPy_OIHty"
string:gsub("^([0-9]{1})", "_")
```

Output would like to be one of the following

```
_fLkQZ73ziBzHMTgaoSBfDb9qa1q3qdqBGwJ4Mw1gkY782VhVr8Itmheq03mPy_OIHty --underscore
AfLkQZ73ziBzHMTgaoSBfDb9qa1q3qdqBGwJ4Mw1gkY782VhVr8Itmheq03mPy_OIHty --Uppercase
afLkQZ73ziBzHMTgaoSBfDb9qa1q3qdqBGwJ4Mw1gkY782VhVr8Itmheq03mPy_OIHty --Lowercase
fLkQZ73ziBzHMTgaoSBfDb9qa1q3qdqBGwJ4Mw1gkY782VhVr8Itmheq03mPy_OIHty --removed
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying a character in a string in Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249629/modifying-a-character-in-a-string-in-lua)

Comment: That topic is no help does not REMOVE the FIRST NUMERIC character "^{1}". As my title even says.

Comment: Lua patterns do not support `{n}` modifier.  To remove: `str = str:gsub("^%d", "")`.  To replace with "A": `str = str:gsub("^%d", "A")`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff While your code helps it is not perfect my string here "bl_fLkQZ__ziBzHMTgaoSBfDb_qa_q_qdqB" As you can see now completely does not contain any numeric values where as I only wanted IF the FIRST CHARACTER is a NUMERIC value to remove that one ONLY, while leaving the rest of the string unaltered is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

```
local str = ...
str = str:gsub("^%d", "_")
```

And yes, this will only replace the number if it is at the beginning of the string. And it will only replace one such character. The `^` at the front of the pattern ensures that the pattern will only be a match if it is at the beginning of the string. And `%d` matches only a single digit character.

If there is no match, then `gsub` returns the string unmodified.